# Visual Studio 2010 extension get reference to solution explorer

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-addins

I'm moving one of my macros over to become a VS2010 extension. I have the line from the macro...

```
Dim items As EnvDTE.UIHierarchyItems = DTE.ToolWindows.SolutionExplorer.UIHierarchyItems
```

I've managed to get DTE - DTE dte = GetService(typeof(SDTE)) as DTE;

but it does contain a ToolWindows Property.

I tried using dte.Windows to get the solution explorer, and that sort of works, but the result doesn't have a UIHierarchyItems.

So in short, what's the best way to get a reference to the solution explorer?

Comment: it's not a vb.net question, the line I give that I'm wanting to translate is VB (macro) but the extension I'm writing is in c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's on [`DTE2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte80.dte2_members.aspx), which is why you didn't find it.  Just replace the `as DTE` with `as DTE2`.